# Postgresql 12.5 "relation already exists" when using "create table if not exists"

Tags: postgresql, partition

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.5 on AWS for millions of events. My tables are partitioned by day by day so when the request comes, I use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... PARTITION OF" syntax for every request.

I expect to skip the command if the table already exists. But PostgreSQL didn't do that. PostgreSQL tried to create tables multiple times instead of skip.

PostgreSQL Error Logs are following

```
2021-05-30 00:00:00 UTC:IP_ADDRESS(24921):dbname@username:[16666]:ERROR:  relation "tablename_20210530" already exists
2021-05-30 00:00:00 UTC:IP_ADDRESS(24921):dbname@username:[16666]:STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename_20210530 PARTITION OF tablename FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-05-30') TO ('2021-05-31')
```

The SQL Exception is following;

```
{
    "errorType": "error",
    "errorMessage": "relation \"tablename_20210530\" already exists",
    "code": "42P07",
    "length": 110,
    "name": "error",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "file": "heap.c",
    "line": "1155",
    "routine": "heap_create_with_catalog",
    "stack": [
        "error: relation \"tablename_20210530\" already exists",
        "    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)",
        "    at Parser.handlePacket (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)",
        "    at Parser.parse (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)",
        "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)",
        "    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)",
        "    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)",
        "    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)",
        "    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)",
        "    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)"
    ]
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

PostgreSQL Version:

```
PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
```

Table Scheme:

```
create table tablename
(
    id bigint default nextval('tablename_partition_id_seq'::regclass) not null,
    col1 timestamp(0) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    col2 varchar(255) not null,
    constraint tablename_partition_pkey
        primary key (id, col1)
)
partition by RANGE ("col1");

create table tablename_20210530
partition of tablename
(
    constraint tablename_20210530_pkey
        primary key (id, col1)
)
FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-05-30 00:00:00') TO ('2021-05-31 00:00:00');
```

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename_20210530 PARTITION OF tablename FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-05-30') TO ('2021-05-31');
```

My code runs the create statement before the insert statement under the thousands of requests. Because every request has a different "col1" value. And I can not control that. so the create table statement is running every time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with any PostgreSQL version. Please say your PostgreSQL version and provide a complete example.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just added the version and examples.

Comment: After fixing the errors in your SQL script (sequence does not exist, duplicate primary key definition), I could not reproduce the problem and got `NOTICE:  relation "tablename_20210530" already exists, skipping`. Either you are doing something different, or you are connected to the wrong database or something like that, or that is not normal PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I'm sorry about the scheme, I copied it from the IDE tool.
Honestly, It's not an important case for us and our logic could handle it when that error has occurred. Also, we never get that error before until now.  I think It's not simple a bug. Maybe It's important for someone that's why I created this question. 

We use that statement for a long time and We didn't get any errors about the partition. It might be related to load. Because like I said, PostgreSQL is running under thousands of requests in a second.

Comment: Did you somehow modify catalogs? Anyway, without being able to reproduce the problem, we won't be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this completely reproducible?  I can see how this could happen under race conditions when multiple sessions try to the create the same table at the same time.  It didn't exist at the time they checked if it existed, but then microseconds later did exist while they were trying to create it.  (I get a different error message, but that might depend on microscopic details of the timing.)

Comment: I didn't any modify catalogs. I agree with @jjanes because this case happens under race conditions and I think it happens only multiple sessions and connections at the same microsecond time. By the way, I checked I/O, CPU, and Memory, I didn't see overload when this occurred. Everything seems normal.